# Regex Pattern to group different variables

Tags: regex, regex-group

I been having trouble trying to find the proper Regex pattern for a string.

The string is this:

```
0|   DIMM: Hynix      |   Not installed    |   DIMM: Micron     |   DIMM: Hynix      |
```

And it can also change to something like this.

```
1|   Not installed    |   DIMM: Samsung    |   DIMM: Hynix      |   DIMM: Hynix      |
```

And the Dimm: *variable* can change to samsung,hynix, micron, or even be Not installed. I want to group each one individually such as, "Hynix", "Micron", "Samsung", AND "Not installed". I do not want to include the DIMM: in there.

I have tried this but only grabs the first variable.

```
(Not installed|(?<=DIMM:)\s[a-zA-Z]+)
```

And copy pasting it 3 more times does not group the other variables. Any Ideas?

Comment: Your regex is already good, I'd suggest something like `((?<=DIMM: )\S+|Not installed)`, but I think you are missing some global flag. What is the language/tool you are using?

Comment: I am going to use it in C++ but right now, i'm using an online Regex tester https://regex101.com/ to test it out in real time.

Answer (score 1):

### Using 1 pattern regex with look behind

Staring out from your regex and leveraging **[Stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev)** comment, you can also use:

```
((?<=DIMM: )\w+|Not installed)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZ7pS5/4)**

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [11-16] `Hynix`
MATCH 2
1.  [26-39] `Not installed`
MATCH 3
1.  [53-59] `Micron`
MATCH 4
1.  [74-79] `Hynix`
MATCH 5
1.  [92-105]    `Not installed`
MATCH 6
1.  [119-126]   `Samsung`
MATCH 7
1.  [140-145]   `Hynix`
MATCH 8
1.  [161-166]   `Hynix`
```

---

### Using 4 patterns regex

I know this is not a pretty regex but might help you doing this:

```
\|\s*(?:DIMM: )?(.*?)\s*\|\s*(?:DIMM: )?(.*?)\s*\|\s*(?:DIMM: )?(.*?)\s*\|\s*(?:DIMM: )?(.*?)\s*\|
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZ7pS5/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Using this regex will give you a match for the complete line capturing content in 4 groups. The disadvantage is that the regex is pretty ugly. Below the result:

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [11-16] `Hynix`
2.  [26-39] `Not installed`
3.  [53-59] `Micron`
4.  [74-79] `Hynix`
MATCH 2
1.  [92-105]    `Not installed`
2.  [119-126]   `Samsung`
3.  [140-145]   `Hynix`
4.  [161-166]   `Hynix`
```

---

### Using 1 pattern regex

Have just found another regex that you might find using:

```
\|\s*(?:DIMM:)?\s?(\w+\s?\w+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZ7pS5/2)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regex uses only 1 capturing group, it's shorter than first one but it's used multiple times to match what you want. Therefore, you will have to add more logic to iterate over the first 4 matches where you know it belongs to a complete line. Below the results:

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [11-16] `Hynix`
MATCH 2
1.  [26-39] `Not installed`
MATCH 3
1.  [53-59] `Micron`
MATCH 4
1.  [74-79] `Hynix`
MATCH 5
1.  [92-105]    `Not installed`
MATCH 6
1.  [119-126]   `Samsung`
MATCH 7
1.  [140-145]   `Hynix`
MATCH 8
1.  [161-166]   `Hynix`
```